# Отправка email сообщений из терминала

Tags: email, macos, sendmail, terminal

Как можно отправить письмо на почту из терминала Mac OS ? 
Пробовал `mail user@domain.com`, пишет EOT и письмо не приходит.

Comment: MacOS не знаю, поэтому комментарием. Стандартный юниксовый `mail` на выходе запускает `/usr/{bin,sbin,lib}/sendmail` (собственно процесс _доставки_ почты; MTA (mail transfer agent), который, в свою очередь, может быть не только «настоящим» sendmail, но и exim, postfix, qmail и т.д. В любом случае, /usr/.../sendmail не зависит от `mail` и, как правило, устанавливается и настраивается отдельно, причём процесс этой настройки не всегда тривиален. Вероятно, в MacOS что-то похожее.

Comment: На сколько я понял в MacOS используется postfix.

Comment: Смотрите /var/log/maillog на предмет ошибок почему не отправилось

Comment: Такого лога нету,по крайней мере по этому пути